# SQL Server : how to combine multiple rows based on two different columns?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, gaps-and-islands

The data I have is similar to:

```
SId       Program      Term       Year       Grad term     Grad year
-------------------------------------------------------------------
1         P           2          2001          3            2005
1         P           3          2001          3            2005
1         P           2          2002          3            2005
2         M           2          2002          2            2004
2         M           3          2002          2            2004
```

Now, I am able to combine the records based on one column 'date', but in my case I need to check both year and term to make sure they are continuous and then combine them.(For each year, the term goes from 1-3). So after executing the query, the result should be:

```
SID  Program  startterm  startyear  EndTerm   EndYear  Gradterm   Gradyear
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
1       P     2         2001         3     2001        3         2005
1       P     2         2002         2     2002        3         2005
2       M     2         2002         3     2002        2         2004
```

The records with continuous year and term are combined together and the record with program-P, term-2, year-2002 wasn't continuous to the previous record, so that record will end up on a separate row with the same start term, start year and end term, end year. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Hi Sam. Can you add the SQL you have so far? It will help us help you edit, you're less likely to have someone write all that for you than give you the edits you may need.

Comment: Hi, the SQL I am working with right now is:  `SELECT ID, year
    ,EffectiveEndyear=
    (
        SELECT TOP 1 year
        FROM [Table Name] b
        WHERE a.ID = b.ID AND b.term > a.term
        ORDER BY a.term
    )
FROM [Table Name] a
ORDER BY id, term;`

Comment: Why `EndYear` in the result is 2002? Shouldn't it be 2001? And what's your SQL version?

Comment: @uzi oops I have edited out that mistake. The version of SQL I am using is Microsoft SQL Server 2016.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query depends on the value of term column and will work if the values are between 1 and 3. It's used to find continues ranges

```
declare @t table (Id int, Program char(1), Term int, Year int, GradTerm int, GradYear int)
insert into @t
values (1, 'P', 2, 2001, 3, 2005)
    , (2, 'P', 3, 2001, 3, 2005), (3, 'P', 2, 2002, 3, 2005)
    , (4, 'M', 2, 2002, 2, 2004), (5, 'M', 3, 2002, 2, 2004)

select
    ID = row_number() over (order by grp), Program, startterm = min(Term)
    , startyear = min(Year), EndTerm = max(Term), EndYear = max(Year), GradTerm, GradYear
from (
    select
        *, grp = Year * 3 + Term - row_number() over (partition by Program, GradTerm, GradYear order by Year, Term)
    from 
        @t
) t
group by Program, GradTerm, GradYear, grp
```

Output:

```
ID  Program  startterm  startyear  EndTerm  EndYear  GradTerm  GradYear
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
1   P        2          2001       3        2001     3         2005
2   P        2          2002       2        2002     3         2005
3   M        2          2002       3        2002     2         2004
```

**EDIT:**

SID should be in `group by` also you need to put it in `row_number`. Also, my  query in the answer has some mistakes. And because of that you could have gotten wrong results. Here's a correct version

```
declare @t table (SID int, Program char(1), Term int, Year int, GradTerm int, GradYear int)
insert into @t
values (1, 'P', 2, 2001, 3, 2005)
    , (1, 'P', 3, 2001, 3, 2005), (1, 'P', 2, 2002, 3, 2005)
    , (2, 'M', 2, 2002, 2, 2004), (2, 'M', 3, 2002, 2, 2004)

select
    SID, Program, startterm = right(min(val), 1)
    , startyear = left(min(val), 4), EndTerm = right(max(val), 1)
    , EndYear = left(max(val), 4), GradTerm, GradYear
from (
    select
        *, grp = Year * 3 + Term - row_number() over (partition by SID, Program, GradTerm, GradYear order by Year, Term)
        , val = concat(Year, Term)
    from 
        @t
) t
group by SID, Program, GradTerm, GradYear, grp
```

Comment: hi @uzi, there was a small mistake in my original question. The ID is unique for a set of records using which we can distinguish student records.So if I put SID in the select statement I will get an error: "SID is invalid since its not grouped or part of aggregate function" and if I put SID in group by, then the output doesn't break when the terms are not continuous. IS there a way to fix this? Thanks

Comment: hi @Sam, updated answer. And provide some sample data if updated query returns wrong results

Comment: hi @uzi, sorry for the late comment but your updated query worked! Thank you very much  :)

Answer (score 1):

Check if this query works for you.Replace your columns and table with the one that you are using.

```
               Select o.Program ,min(o.Term) AS StartTerm,
                 o.year AS StartYear,
                max(Term) AS EndTerm,
                 (Select max(g.year) from #GradProg g where g.[Grad term] = 
                       o.[Grad term] AND  g.Program = o.Program AND g.[Grad 
                  year] = o.[Grad year]) AS EndYear,
                 [Grad term],[Grad year]
               from #GradProg o
              group by   Program ,[Grad term],[Grad year],Year
              order by [Grad year] desc
```

Comment: Hi @rmehra, that query is working for me with one small issue. For each id, even though there is no break in term between years, its creating separate row. For eg if the input is: ` ID -1 program-phd term-2 year-2002, ID-2 program-phd term-3 year-2002, ID-3 program-phd term-1 year-2003` is supposed to give the output as one row since there is no break in term. However, the above query will give me two rows based on years 2002, 2003.

Comment: In the example that you have shown in the question there are 2 rows for program 'P' , going by your req in the comment , we should have one row only, if i'm understanding corrrectly? if that is the case then we will not group by year , rather pick the minimum and max year

Comment: Hi, I understand your point but the reason there are two rows for 'P' in the question is because there is a break after year-2001 term-3. Since there is no row for year-2002 term-1, the output should show two different rows.

Answer (score 1):

```
 /***This is a raw query which should be optimized using self joins***/     
 Select o.Program ,min(o.Term) AS StartTerm,
 min(o.year) AS StartYear,
 max(Term) AS EndTerm,
max(o.year) AS EndYear,
(Select max(g.year) from #GradProg g where g.[Grad term] = o.[Grad term] 
AND  g.Program = o.Program AND g.[Grad year] = o.[Grad year]) AS EndYear,
[Grad term],[Grad year]
,Iscontinous   
 from 
(
  Select *,
  case when (Select i.Program from #GradProg i where i.Term = t.nextterm and 
  i.Year = t.nexttermyear)  is not null then
   1
  when t.year = (Select max(y.Year) from #GradProg y) and t.Term = (Select 
  max(tm.Term) from #GradProg tm where t.Year = tm.Year)  then 
   1
 else
  0
 end as Iscontinous     
  from 

 (Select * ,

    case o1.Term when 3 then 1 
    else (o1.Term +1) 
    end as nextterm,
    case o1.Term when 3 then o1.Year + 1 
    else (o1.Year) 
    end as nexttermyear    
    from #GradProg o1

  )t
 )o
group by   o.Program ,o.[Grad term],o.[Grad year],
Iscontinous 
order by [Grad year] desc
/*********end *************/
```

Comment: Hi @Sam , I understood your req , please see if the above query solves your problem

Comment: Hi @rmehra76, the above query is giving me an error:                  
  "Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 34
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression."

Comment: Use top 1 in the subquery part , may be you have multiple rec in the criteria (Select top 1 i.Program from #GradProg i where i.Term = t.nextterm and 
  i.Year = t.nexttermyear

Comment: Hey @rmehra76, Unfortunately it didnt. The error went away but the output is not right. As input I gave a  record who was enrolled from year-1990 term-1 till year-1993 term-2 but had a break at year-1990 term-2. The expected output was two rows  which are `startyear-1990 startterm-1 endyear-1990 endterm-1` and second row- `startyear-1990 startterm-3 endyear-1993 endterm-2`. but the output I got was one row `startyear-1990 startterm-1 endyear-1993 endterm-3`. The end term was 3 which was not a part of the input

Comment: Can you please share the raw data?

Comment: `ID           Program   year     term    gradterm     gradyear                                                                                    
8533 MSBIOM  1989 3 3 1991
8533 MSBIOM  1990 1 3 1991
8533 MSBIOM  1990 3 3 1991
8533 MSBIOM  1991 1 3 1991
8533 MSBIOM  1991 2 3 1991
8533 MSBIOM  1991 3 3 1991
8533 PHDBIM          1993 3 1 1996
8533 PHDBIM          1994 1 1 1996
8533 PHDBIM      1994 2 1 1996
8533 PHDBIM          1994 3 1 1996
8533 PHDBIM          1995 1 1 1996
8533 PHDBIM          1995 3 1 1996`      I am not able to align the data in a better way in a comment. Sorry

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168328/discussion-between-rmehra76-and-sam).

Comment: MSBIOM 1 1990 1 1990 3 1991

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
    create table #tmp (id int, Program VARCHAR(1),Term INT,[Year] INT,[Grad Term] INT, [Grad year] INT)

    insert into #tmp 
    SELECT 1,'P',2,2001,3,2005
    union 
    SELECT 2,'P',3,2001,3,2005
    union
    SELECT 3,'P',2,2002,3,2005
    union
    SELECT 4,'M',2,2002,2,2004
    union
    SELECT 5,'M',3,2002,2,2004

    ;with cte 
    AS(

        select *,
            RANK() OVER(partition by Program,[Year] order by id,[year],term) as [Minrank],
            RANK() OVER(partition by Program,[Year] order by id desc,[year]desc,term desc) as [Maxrank]
        from #tmp
    )


    select c1.id,c2.Program,c1.term as Startterm,c1.[year] as StartYear,
    c2.term as EndTerm, c2.[Year] As EndYear,c1.[Grad Term],c2.[Grad year] from cte c1
    JOIN cte c2 on c1.Program=c2.program and c1.[year]=c2.[year] and c1.Minrank=c2.[Maxrank]
    WHERE c1.Minrank=1
    order by c1.id


    drop table #tmp
```

Comment: Hi @Sahi, I tried the above query and in many result rows, for the same year, the end term is less than the start term. for eg: `id-1051      program-PHDMAN       Startterm-2       StartYear-2017        EndTerm-1   EndYear-2017   GradTerm-NULL       Gradyear-NULL`